# Installing a library in Python

Tags: python, macos

I am new to MAC OS, and I need to install a library in Python called [btmorph](https://bitbucket.org/btorb/btmorph.git/src/master/docs/readme.rst?fileviewer=file-view-default).
In order to install it, I have to write these commands in the terminal:

```
git clone https://bitbucket.org/btorb/btmorph.git
cd btmorph
export PYTHONPATH=$(pwd):$PYTHONPATH
```

and then they said:

> The above commands will temporarily set your $PYTHONPATH. Add the appropriate path in your .bashrc to make add the package permanently.

the first commands were executed successfully, but the last one is asking for PYTHONPATH which I don't know, and I am not sure if I want to change it permanently!

and then to test it I have to write:

```
nosetests -v --nocapture tests/structs_test.py
nosetests -v --nocapture tests/stats_test.py
```

I am sorry but I am a beginner in MAC.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Does the btmorph folder contain a setup.py??

Comment: You can remove the line from `.bashrc` to easily revert the change.

Comment: No, I only found python files (no setup.py), docs, examples and tests

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus the third command couldn't be executed because I don't know my PAYTHONPATH and where to write it in the command itself.

Comment: You don't need to know it. You just append the directory at the beggining of it.

Comment: Type `nano ~/.bashrc` and insert a line `export PYTHONPATH=<path-to-btmorph>:$PYTHONPATH`, replacing `<path-to-btmorph>` with the path your module is in. If you remove the line, the change will be reverted soon enough.

Comment: No. use path to `btmorph`, not to python. And, don't wrap it in `$()`.

Comment: I wrote this:

nano ~/.bashrc export PYTHONPATH=</Users/TheMaestro/btmorph>:$PYTHONPATH

and got this: 

Received SIGHUP or SIGTERM

and the test failed

Comment: I'd omit angle brackets. I can't help you further, I'm not using this module.

Comment: Yea don't worry, thank you very much ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install a python library that does not have a `setup.py` file, the location of the library's root directory needs to be appended to the `$PYTHONPATH` environment variable for Python to be able to locate it.  This is what the third command `export PYTHONPATH=$(pwd):$PYTHONPATH` does on a temporary basis.

To do it more permanently, that line, or more specifically, a similar one, needs to find its way into one of the files that the `bash` shell loads every time a new Terminal window is opened.  `~/.bashrc` is one of these files but `~/.bash_profile` is another, and one that is arguably [the better choice for a simple install on Mac OS X](http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html).

For the btmorph example specifically, there is a one-liner that can get the job done for you.  I've tested it myself here, and *so long as you have all of btmorph's dependencies installed*, python should load the library with no problem.

If you have already executed the first two commands you listed, you should already be inside the directory into which you cloned the btmorph source code.  On a default Terminal session, your prompt should read something like `Maestros-Mac:btmorph TheMaestro$`.  If it does, you're ready to go. (You can also use the `pwd` or **p**rint **w**orking **d**irectory command to see the full path to your current directory)

Copying the following command and pasting it in your Terminal window will write the correct line to your `.bash_profile` file (or create the file and write the line to it if it doesn't already exist) and then load that file.

`echo \export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$PWD>>~/.bash_profile && source ~/.bash_profile`

Once you have run this command, you should be able to `import btmorph` from within a Python interpreter, and the change should persist over time.

Keep in mind that since the location of the btmorph folder where you created it has been hardcoded into the $PYTHONPATH variable (that's what the `$PWD` part of the command does), you cannot move the btmorph folder from where it is now, or Python won't be able to find it anymore.  If you want to store the folder  somewhere else, I would `cd` to that folder and `git clone` it in there to start with.

Comment: Yea the .bash_profile has been modified successfully, but the interpreter in PyCharm couldn't import the library!

The .bash_profile has now a new line:
export PYTHONPATH=/Users/TheMaestro/btmorph

Furthermore, I tried to delete the complete lines in the .bash_profile which are all about Python paths (2.7, 3.5)  and the python code (except the btmorph) continued working normally.

Comment: Oh PyCharm.  I love it, but it can make a few tasks incredibly difficult. PyCharm, unlike Terminal, doesn't seem to get its `$PYTHONPATH` value from either `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`, but from its own settings. (I get the impression it may import settings once from somewhere, but for any updates after that, you're on your own.)  For version 2016.1, the dialogue to add a custom path [is thoroughly hidden](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24197970/pycharm-import-external-library), but it is doable.