# How to import ros to PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, ros

I am developing a robot using the ros framework. As ide, I use PyCharm. But I can’t import ros into it. On the ros site there is the article about ide http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs. There is information about using ros with pycharm. I have to modify the .desktop file, but I installed PyCharm using a snap from the software center. Where can I find the .desktop file for snap applications? Can there be another method to import ros into PyCharm?

Edit:
@hug Yes, I launched this command here is the result

```
/snap/pycharm-community/103/meta/gui/pycharm-community.desktop
/snap/pycharm-community/103/snap/gui/pycharm-community.desktop
/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/pycharm-community_pycharm-community.desktop
/var/tmp/pycharm-community.desktop.swp
```

I think that the .swp file has remained since the last reinstallation of PyCharm. I reinstalled when I tried to do it myself and realized that I had broken the program.

Comment: Can you find the .desktop file with `locate .desktop | grep pycharm`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use from the auto-suggestion with ROS packages in Pycharm IDE, you could do the following instructions:

1. *File* > *Settings* (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> as shortcut)> *Project:*  > *Project interpreter*.
2. In the project interpreter dropdown list, you can specify *ROS Python* interpreter by selecting the appropriate from the list.

---

[**NOTE**]:

You could add a virtual environment with the above instructions, then you should add ROS distpackages (`roslib`) on it with [this instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24206781/3702377).

ROS distpackages path that you need: `/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/distpackages`

Answer (score 3):

Follow these video instructions for setting up pycharm with ROS.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lTew9mbXrAs

Debugging, code completion, imports, etc all behave correctly. You can do all your python ROS development entirely in pycharm.

In summary:

- Create a virtual environment `virtualenv venv --system-site-packages`
- Source your virtualenv and your ROS workspace and launch pycharm from this (sourced) terminal. (enable Shell Scripts in the JetBrains Toolbox to allow command-line `pycharm`)
- Under the project structure you will "Add Content Root":
- Keep `[ros_workspace]/src` (which should already be there). Mark all the the `src` folders containing python code as "Sources".
- add `/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages`
- add `[ros_workspace]/devel/lib/python3/dist-packages`. Exclude any packages in `[ros_workspace]/devel/lib/python3/dist-packages` that contain source code (e.g. are not just message packages). If you have packages that contain both source and messages, you will need to separate these for pycharm to resolve imports correctly in the editor

More details and explanation in the video

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is struggling with getting PyCharm intellisense and autocomplete to work with your own ros python packages, this [answer](https://github.com/team-vigir/flexbe_behavior_engine/issues/34#) was very illuminating.

Basically PyCharm does not dynamically interpret the `devel/` space `__init__.py` for your packages, so at runtime the packages are available, but no intellisense in PyCharm. Changing the Project Structure settings to add your `<package>/src` as a Source folder solved the issue for me. Bit of a pain, but hey, intellisense is back!