# Is It possible to develop ROS in Python without installing ROS on the development computer?

Tags: python, ide, pycharm, ros, rospy

Is it possible to get the `rospy` lib into PyCharm for autocompleting and highlighting error without installing ROS on my MAC?

Comment: Activating ROS autocomplete in Pycharm IDE is there in this [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53637038/how-to-import-ros-to-pycharm/53639325#53639325), but I think you need to install the ROS to get the `roslib` and its `/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/distpackages` content. So you need to install ROS at least the ROS-Base version instead of the full version.

Comment: IT WORKS PERFECTLY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyCharm Professional edition allows for the use of [Remote Interpreters](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-remote-interpreters-via-ssh.html).  You would need to install ROS either on a remote machine or a local VM and then connect PyCharm to it over SSH.  You can also use a [Docker Interpreter](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-docker-as-a-remote-interpreter.html) and simply install ROS in a docker container.  For simplicity you could start with an existing ROS Docker container.

Either way, you'll need to ensure that the environment is effectively activated so that PyCharm can find the ROS python packages and not just the OS packages.

Comment: Thank you for this tip I added to my Pycharm Prof.

Answer (score -1):

No, this is not possible, because without the package installed PyCharm does not know what to autocomplete.

Comment: is there any other way to make access to the rospy lib without install the whole ROS on the Mac?