# roslz is imported in the pycharm terminal but not in the python code. why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ros, ros2, rosbag

I have installed the ROS Noetic by following the commands in [this link](http://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Ubuntu) in ubuntu 20.4. the installation seems to be successful. When I am importing the `roslz4`in the Pycharm Terminal, it is importing it as follows:

```
(hsi-env) es@es-System-Product-Name:~/PycharmProjects/1-RGBD$ python
Python 3.8.16 (default, Jun 12 2023, 18:09:05) 
[GCC 11.2.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import roslz4
>>>
```

However in my python code, I am getting the following error, which is related to a `import roslz4`:

```
    /home/es/anaconda3/envs/hsi-env/bin/python /home/es/PycharmProjects/1-RGBD/BAG2RGB.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/es/PycharmProjects/1-RGBD/BAG2RGB.py", line 12, in <module>
    import roslz4
  File "/home/es/anaconda3/envs/hsi-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/roslz4/__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    from ._roslz4 import *
ImportError: libroslz4.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Do you know how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import ros to PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53637038/how-to-import-ros-to-pycharm)