# Integrating ROS with pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pytorch, ros

I wanted to run ROS in PyCharm, but could not find that .desktop file as mentioned [here](http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs#PyCharm_.28community_edition.29) in which changes should be made. Moreover, I want to use the same environment that is created for `PyTorch`, do not want to change the interpreter. Can someone help me out with this?

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a virtual environment with the following instructions, then you should add ROS distpackages (`roslib`) on it with [this instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24206781/3702377).

1. *File* > *Settings* (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> as shortcut)> *Project:*  > *Project interpreter*.
2. In the project interpreter dropdown list, you can specify *ROS Python* interpreter by selecting the appropriate from the list.

ROS distpackages path that you need: `/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/distpackages`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But by changing the interpretter I will loose my PyTorch environment which I created, Moreover I am using Python 3.6 for PyTorch and ROS is having Python 2.7, Will that be a problem?

Comment: You should gather all repositories such as `rospkg`, `pytorch` and `python3` on an environment and use this path.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I will try that if I feel any difficulty I will get back to you.