# How can I import system packages (i.e. rospy, std_msgs, geoemtry_msgs) into my virtual environment that's using python2?

Tags: python, ros, catkin, px4

Previously, I had installed PX4 Firmware, ROS, and Gazebo using:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PX4/Devguide/master/build_scripts/ubuntu_sim_ros_melodic.sh
bash ubuntu_sim_ros_melodic.sh
```

I believe these two lines install all the packages needed for ROS and whatnot and I just needed to install python 2.7 because I am running ros-melodic. However, I had tried to install anaconda and then I tried to import the needed packages (rospy, std_msgs, geometry_msgs <- couldn't find geometry_msgs), but it was running on Python 3.8. I decided to uninstall anaconda in the end because I keep hearing that it is difficult to work with ros in a conda environment. Since I already have python2.7 on my machine for some reason, I just went ahead to create a python virtual environment instead and there is a lot of tutorial on how to do this anyways.

First I created a ros workspace with catkin

```
mkdir -p drone/src
catkin_make
cd src
catkin_create_pkgs bigdrone std_msgs geometry_msgs rospy
```

I open Pycharm-Professional and set the interpreter from drone/venv/bin/python. Now I tried to import my packages again, but all of them are missing. I thought maybe it is because it can't find the packages because it is a virtual environment, so I switched to the python in /usr/bin/python2.7. The packages I needed are still missing but I do have access to some like rosdep and whatnot. In addition when I simply run on the terminal:

```
python
>>> import rospy
>>> import std_msgs
>>> import geometry_msgs
```

Everything seems to work just fine for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it cannot find those packages in Pycharm, but can from your terminal, is you have run `source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash` in your terminal. This file sets environmental variables and will update `PYHTONPATH` to include ros specific modules like the ones you mentioned. You can probably get it to work by starting Pycharm from a terminal that has the file in `/opt/` sourced.

That being said, a more complete solution is to add the ros distpackages to your virtual environment. You can find the steps to add an external package [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24197970/pycharm-import-external-library/24206781#24206781) and the path you want to add is `/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/distpackages`. After that you can go to File > Settings > Project: > Project interpreter. From there you can specify the ROS Python interpreter from the list.